# Why my Alert message display out of my DIV HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

My message display out of my DIV HTML
How do I resolve this?

I need to display this message within the div. If I repeat this code, it appears in the same place every time, I just want to display it in its own div and not invade others. My big problem it's the display message. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
    <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      jhadfjadfjasf
      ajdfhkhasdjfas
      ajdfhjadfa
      ajdfhkajsdfh
      <div class="sidney">
         <img src="https://eitrawmaterials.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/person-icon.png" width="220px" height="220px">
         <div id="baselayer">
            <input type="button" class="testx" value="SubLevel" onclick="showFrontLayer();" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Job Description" onclick="showFrontLayers();"/>
            <div id="bg_mask">
               <div id="frontlayer">
                  <div class="containers">
                     <input type="button"  value="X" onclick="hideFrontLayer();" style="position: absolute;top:5%;right:5%;"/>
                     O Product Owner é a pessoa que define os itens que compõem o Product Backlog e os prioriza nas Sprint Planning Meetings.
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bg_masks">
               <div id="frontlayers">
                  <input type="button" value="X" onclick="hideFrontLayers();" style="position: absolute;top:5%;right:5%;"/>
                  O Product Owner.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <style>
         .sidney{
         width: 250px;
         height: 250px;
         background-color: black;
         border:20px;
         }
      </style>
      <img src="https://eitrawmaterials.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/person-icon.png" width="170px" height="150px">
      <style>
         #testx{
         position: absolute;
         top: 0px;
         left: 0px%;
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         background-color: #555;
         color: white;
         font-size: 16px;
         padding: 12px 24px;
         border: none;
         cursor: pointer;
         border-radius: 5px;
         text-align: center;}
         #bg_mask{
         position: absolute;
         top: 0px;
         right: 0;  
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         margin: auto;
         margin-top: 0px;
         width: 981px;
         height: 610px;
         background : url("img_dot_white.jpg") center;
         z-index: 0;
         visibility: hidden;
         } 
         #frontlayer{
         position: absolute;
         top: 0px;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
         padding : 30px;
         width: 180px;
         height: 100px;
         background-color: orange;
         visibility: hidden;
         border: 1px solid black;
         z-index: 1;
         } 
         #bg_masks {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;  
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         margin: auto;
         margin-top: 0px;
         width: 981px;
         height: 610px;
         background : url("img_dot_white.jpg") center;
         z-index: 0;
         visibility: hidden;
         } 
         #frontlayers {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
         padding : 30px;
         width: 180px;
         height: 100px;
         background-color: orange;
         visibility: hidden;
         border: 1px solid black;
         z-index: 1;
         } 
      </style>
      <script>
         function showFrontLayer() {
           document.getElementById('bg_mask').style.visibility='visible';
           document.getElementById('frontlayer').style.visibility='visible';
         }
         function hideFrontLayer() {
           document.getElementById('bg_mask').style.visibility='hidden';
           document.getElementById('frontlayer').style.visibility='hidden';
         
         }
         
      </script>
      <script>
         function showFrontLayers() {
           document.getElementById('bg_masks').style.visibility='visible';
           document.getElementById('frontlayers').style.visibility='visible';
         }
         function hideFrontLayers() {
           document.getElementById('bg_masks').style.visibility='hidden';
           document.getElementById('frontlayers').style.visibility='hidden';
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: well the code is positioned absolutely.

Comment: You should add the doctype declaration

Answer (score 0):

add **position: relative;** to this class **.sidney** (you can find it on line 31)